# can i use resize box in align

Tags: spacing, equations, align, resize, labelling

I have this equation that goes off page when complied. its so large that `\tiny` doesn't cut it. I need to use resize box but the equation is in an align environment. equation needs to be labelled as a block, is that possible?

ps: the equation cannot be changed

any suggestions?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[inner=3.8cm, outer=1.3cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=1.2cm]{geometry}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % <-- new

\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
c_{11}&=1\\
c_{12}&=-\frac{160 {x_{n+1}^9}+2520 h {x_{n+1}^8}+16560 {h^2} {x_{n+1}^7}+58800 {h^3} {x_{n+1}^6}+121842 {h^4} {x_{n+1}^5}+147735 {h^5} {x_{n+1}^4}+98010 {h^6} {x_{n+1sing}^3}+28350 {h^7} {x_{n+1}^2}-473977 {h^9}}{2041200 {h^8}}\\
c_{13}&=\frac{320 {x_{n+1}^9}+4680 h {x_{n+1}^8}+27360 {h^2} {x_{n+1}^7}+78960 {h^3} {x_{n+1}^6}+102564 {h^4} {x_{n+1}^5}-9135 {h^5} {x_{n+1}^4}-197940 {h^6} {x_{n+1}^3}-237330 {h^7} {x_{n+1}^2}-113400 {h^8} {x_{n+1}}+343921 {h^9}}{113400 {h^8}}\\
c_{14}&=-\frac{1120 {x_{n+1}^9}+15750 h {x_{n+1}^8}+86760 {h^2} {x_{n+1}^7}+225750 {h^3} {x_{n+1}^6}+223524 {h^4} {x_{n+1}^5}-171675 {h^5} {x_{n+1}^4}-578340 {h^6} {x_{n+1}^3}-396900 {h^7} {x_{n+1}^2}+594011 {h^9}}{85050 {h^8}}\\
c_{15}&=\frac{560 {x_{n+1}^{9}}+7560 h {x_{n+1}^{8}}+39240 {{h}^{2}} {x_{n+1}^{7}}+92400 {{h}^{3}} {x_{n+1}^{6}}+68607 {{h}^{4}} {x_{n+1}^{5}}-101745 {{h}^{5}} {x_{ n+1}^{4}}-210735 {{h}^{6}} {x_{n+1}^{3}}-99225 {{h}^{7}} {x_{n+1}^{2}}+203338 {{h}^{9}}}{18900 {{h}^{8}}} \\
c_{16}&=-\frac{1120 {x_{n+1}^{9}}+14490 h {x_{n+1}^{8}}+70920 {{h}^{2}} {x_{n+1}^{7}}+152250 {{h}^{3}} {x_{n+1}^{6}}+84924 {{h}^{4}} {x_{n+1}^{5}}-191205 {{h}^{5}} {x_{n+1}^{4}}-310380 {{h}^{6}} {x_{n+1}^{3}}-132300 {{h}^{7}} {x_{n+1}^{2}}+310181 {{h}^{9}}}{28350 {{h}^{8}}}\\
c_{17}&=\frac{2240 {x_{n+1}^{9}}+27720 h {x_{n+1}^{8}}+128160 {{h}^{2}} {x_{n+1}^{7}}+253680 {{h}^{3}} {x_{n+1}^{6}}+109116 {{h}^{4}} {x_{n+1}^{5}}-336735 {{h}^{5}} {x_{n+1}^{4}}-487620 {{h}^{6}} {x_{n+1}^{3}}-198450 {{h}^{7}} {x_{n+1}^{2}}+501889 {{h}^{9}}}{68040 {{h}^{8}}}\\
c_{18}&=-\frac{160 {x_{n+1}^{9}}+1890 h {x_{n+1}^{8}}+8280 {{h}^{2}} {x_{n+1}^{7}}+15330 {{h}^{3}} {x_{n+1} ^{6}}+5292 {{h}^{4}} {x_{n+1}^{5}}-21105 {{h}^{5}} {x_{n+1}^{4}}-28620 {{h}^{6}} {x_{n+1}^3}-11340 {{h}^{7}} {x_{n+1}^{2}}+30113 {{h}^{9}}}{9450 {h^8}}\\
c_{19}&=\frac{1120 {x_{n+1}^9}+12600 h {x_{n+1}^8}+52560 {h^2} {x_{n+1}^7}+92400 {h^3} {x_{n+1}^6}+26334 {h^4} {x_{n+1}^5}-130725 {h^5} {x_{n+1}^4}-169890 {h^6} {x_{n+1}^3}-66150 {h^7} {x_{n+1}^2}+181751 {h^9}}{226800 {h^8}}\\
c_{(10)}&=-\frac{160 {x_{n+1}^9}+1710 h {x_{n+1}^8}+6840 {h^2} {x_{n+1}^7}+11550 {h^3} {x_{n+1}^6}+2772 {h^4} {x_{n+1}^5}-16695 {h^5} {x_{n+1}^4}-21060 {h^6} {x_{n+1}^3}-8100 {h^7}{x_{n+1}^2}+22823 {h^9}}{255150{h^8}}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you are printing on paper there is no point scaling that small as it will not be readable, perhaps OK for a digital format with zoom  `\resizebox{...}{!}{$\begin{aligned}....\end{aligned}$}`

Comment: @Megamind you posted the content and it has a perpetual license, if you want things deleted then flag for moderator action and they can decide what happens: [Deleting questions in response to OP requests](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1343). Ruining your question (and answers) by editing the question is not okay, I see you tried to edit out another answer to your question too: [Changing a Wide Matrix from Landscape to Portrait Orientation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/684009)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give up with those unreadable long fractions and split the numerators.

In the code below I removed all unnecessary braces.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % <-- new
\usepackage[inner=3.8cm, outer=1.3cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=1.2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
c_{11}&=1\\
c_{12}&=-\frac{1}{2041200h^8}\bigl(
  \begin{aligned}[t]
    & 160 x_{n+1}^9 + 2520 h x_{n+1}^8 + 16560 h^2 x_{n+1}^7 + 58800 h^3 x_{n+1}^6 \\
    & + 121842 h^4x_{n+1}^5+147735h^5x_{n+1}^4 + 98010 h^6 x_{n+1}^3 \\
    & + 28350 h^7 x_{n+1}^2 - 473977 h^9 \bigr)
  \end{aligned}
\\
c_{13}&=\frac{1}{113400 h^8} \bigl(
  \begin{aligned}[t]
  & 320 x_{n+1}^9 + 4680 h x_{n+1}^8 + 27360 h^2 x_{n+1}^7 + 78960 h^3 x_{n+1}^6 \\
  & + 102564 h^4 x_{n+1}^5 - 9135 h^5 x_{n+1}^4 - 197940 h^6 x_{n+1}^3 \\
  & - 237330 h^7 x_{n+1}^2 - 113400 h^8 x_{n+1} + 343921 h^9 \bigr)
  \end{aligned}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Fix the following lines in a similar way.

[image]

Compare with what you'd get using `\resizebox`.

[image]

Comment: Hello pls can you delete the screenshot

Comment: @Megamind May I know what is the purpose of asking to delete the `screenshot`? Also note that `egreg` is one of a legend in `TeX` community, he never do the unwanted things.

Comment: @Megamind Afraid of being accused of plagiarism? *You* posted the equation.

Comment: Apologies to all,  it seems I have used a wrong approach in solving my issue. Apologies to egreg. I am still learning the ropes

Comment: @egreg Could you add the details of how you achieved adding resizebox to make the last screenshot? The syntax is what I am looking for. Thanks

Comment: @Tsaras Why would you want to replicate such a horror?

Comment: @egreg For an automated system that needs to fit results on the page. It is too hard to make it smart enough to know where to change lines.

Comment: @Tsaras Please ask a new question with some more details

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use resizebox, rather split long numerator in two lines by use of the `\splitfrac` of `mathtools`:

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

Only first three lines:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[inner=3.8cm, outer=1.3cm, 
            top=2.5cm, bottom=1.2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % <-- new
\usepackage{amssymb, mathtools}
\allowdisplaybreaks

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
c_{11}  & = 1\\
c_{12}  & = -\frac{\splitfrac{160x_{n+1}^9 + 2520hx_{n+1}^8 + 16560h^2 x_{n+1}^7 + 58800h^3 x_{n+1}^6 +
                              121842h^4x_{n+1}^5 +} 
                              {147735h^5x_{n+1}^4 +98010h^6x_{n+1sing}^3 +28350h^7x_{n+1}^2 - 473977h^9}}
                  {2041200h^8}  \\[2ex]
c_{13}  & =  \frac{\splitfrac{320x_{n+1}^9 +4680hx_{n+1}^8 + 27360h^2x_{n+1}^7 + 78960 h^3 x_{n+1}^6 +
                              102564h^4x_{n+1}^5 - }
                             {9135h^5x_{n+1}^4 - 197940h^6x_{n+1}^3 - 237330h^7x_{n+1}^2 - 113400h^8 x_{n+1} + 343921 h^9}}
                  {113400 {h^8}}%\\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```